# How to update the ListView after adding new items?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am working on a grocery list app and having trouble refreshing the list view after adding a new item. After I add a new item in the database the ListView is not refreshed. If I go in the item details page and then come back to main activity the onCreate is called again and it refreshes it correctly.

If I call the refresh method in the addItemToDb() (on button clicked) method it duplicates my items but does not add them to the database.
Has anyone had this problem before???
Here is the code:

The list view adapter

```
    public class ItemListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemModel> {
    Activity activity;
    int layoutResource;
    ArrayList<ItemModel> itemModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ItemListViewAdapter(Activity act, int resource, ArrayList<ItemModel> data) {
        super(act, resource, data);

        activity = act;
        layoutResource = resource;
        itemModelArrayList = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemModelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemModel getItem(int position) {
        return itemModelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null || (row.getTag()) == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.hItemName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_productName);
            holder.hItemPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_productPrice);
            holder.hItemType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_productType);
            holder.hCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_checkBox);
            holder.hItemEdit = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.custom_row_edit);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.hModel = getItem(position);

        holder.hItemName.setText(holder.hModel.getItemName());
        holder.hItemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(holder.hModel.getItemPrice()));
        holder.hItemType.setText(holder.hModel.getItemType());

        holder.hItemEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int itemID = holder.hModel.getItemId();
                String itemName = holder.hModel.getItemName();
                String itemPrice = String.valueOf(holder.hModel.getItemPrice());
                String itemType = holder.hModel.getItemType();
                String itemDate = holder.hModel.getItemDate();

                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ItemDetail.class);

                intent.putExtra("id", itemID);
                intent.putExtra("product", itemName);
                intent.putExtra("price", itemPrice);
                intent.putExtra("type", itemType);
                intent.putExtra("date", itemDate);

                startActivity(activity, intent, null);
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ItemModel hModel;
        TextView hItemName;
        TextView hItemPrice;
        TextView hItemType;
        TextView hItemDate;
        CheckBox hCheckBox;
        ImageView hItemEdit;
    }
}
```

And main activity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    itemNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_productName);
    itemPriceText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_productPrice);
    itemTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_spinner);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_addButton);
    saveListButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_fab);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.productTypes, R.layout.spinner_item);
    itemTypeSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


    //USE BUTTONS
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    saveListButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //LIST_VIEW
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_listView);

    //calling methods
    refreshData();
}

    public void refreshData() {
    modelArrayListContainer.clear();

    //GET ITEMS FROM DB
    ArrayList<ItemModel> modelArrayListFromDB = dbHandler.getAllItems();

    for (int i = 0; i < modelArrayListFromDB.size(); i++) {

        int ditemID = modelArrayListFromDB.get(i).getItemId();
        String dItemName = modelArrayListFromDB.get(i).getItemName();
        double dItemPrice = modelArrayListFromDB.get(i).getItemPrice();
        String dItemType = modelArrayListFromDB.get(i).getItemType();
        String dItemDate = modelArrayListFromDB.get(i).getItemDate();

        ItemModel newModel = new ItemModel();

        newModel.setItemId(ditemID);
        newModel.setItemName(dItemName);
        newModel.setItemPrice((int) dItemPrice);
        newModel.setItemType(dItemType);
        newModel.setItemDate(dItemDate);

        modelArrayListContainer.add(newModel);
    }

    //setup Adapter
    itemListViewAdapter = new ItemListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_product_layout_activity_main, modelArrayListContainer);
    listView.setAdapter(itemListViewAdapter);
    itemListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

        public void addItemToDb() {
        ItemModel model = new ItemModel();

        String spinnerValue = itemTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            model.setItemName(itemNameText.getText().toString().trim());      model.setItemPrice(Double.parseDouble((itemPriceText.getText().toString().trim())));
model.setItemType(spinnerValue);

            dbHandler.addItem(model);
            dbHandler.close();

            Log.v(TAG, "::addItemToDb - itemAdded");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `refreshData()` in your `addItemToDb` function like:

```
     public void addItemToDb() {
        ItemModel model = new ItemModel();

        String spinnerValue = itemTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            model.setItemName(itemNameText.getText().toString().trim());      model.setItemPrice(Double.parseDouble((itemPriceText.getText().toString().trim())));
model.setItemType(spinnerValue);

            dbHandler.addItem(model);
            dbHandler.close();

            Log.v(TAG, "::addItemToDb - itemAdded");
            refreshData();

        }
```

But if you need to update data automatically from database, you need to use `CursorAdaptor` and use `Content Providers`

**UPDATE**

Also change your getAllItems() function in dbhandler and include the following statement in the first line of the function:

```
modelArrayList.clear();
```

Comment: I tried calling the refreshData() in addItemToDb function before. the problem is when the app starts no item is displayed in the listview untill i add a new item. And if i call it in the onCreate and again in the addItemToDb function it duplicates my items

Comment: what happens if you add two items in a row? still you get duplicated list?

Comment: Yes. with the refreshData() in the onCreate and on the addItemToDb function it looks like this:

Comment: Yes. with the refreshData() in the onCreate and on the addItemToDb function it looks like this: If i have one item in the DB (lets say apples ) and i add another (lets say orange) it shows me 4 items in total (3 apples and 1 orange).

Comment: the order of display is apples -- apples --- oranges --- apples

Comment: //get all items
    public ArrayList<ItemModel> getAllItems() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Constants.PRODUCT_ID, Constants.PRODUCT_NAME, Constants.PRODUCT_PRICE, Constants.PRODUCT_TYPE, Constants.PRODUCT_DATE},
                null, null, null, null, Constants.PRODUCT_DATE + " DESC");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

Comment: ItemModel model = new ItemModel();
                //format date
                java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                String data = dateFormat.format(new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PRODUCT_DATE))));

                model.setItemId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constants.PRODUCT_ID)));
                model.setItemName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constants.PRODUCT_NAME)));

Comment: model.setItemPrice(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constants.PRODUCT_PRICE)));
                model.setItemType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Constants.PRODUCT_TYPE)));
                model.setItemDate(data);

                modelArrayList.add(model);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return modelArrayList;
    }

Comment: @Adrian I mean update your code with the full function. Also where modelArrayList is defined?

Comment: the array is defined     private ArrayList<ItemModel> modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: If it is simple for you i cand send u the whole app :)

Comment: check the updated answer, the problem is with your modelArrayList and that is the data just get added to it and never get cleared

Comment: tanks you are right i added modelArrayList.clear(); at the begining of getAllItems() and know it works ok. Tanks a lot ...i didn't see the update :)

Comment: @Adrian glad to hear that